Combine 4 node_exporter data in one grafana table
grafana dashboard UI
I have setup four (4) node exporters on different servers(web01, web02, app01, and app02) that are giving their metrics data to one prometheus server now I want to create one table in the Grafana dashboard where U can see all the servers with information like CPU utilization, memory utilization, n/w utilization, and disk iops. So please help me with how to transform data into a table and display it in a list (For reference, see the above image).
I have tried so many solutions, but I am not able to create tables for four (4) servers at a time. I have created tables for one server.

I'd say general outline of the process is something like this: 1. add query for each value you want to see, 2. switch all queries to table format, 3. join all of them into single table using Join by field transformation.

Is that what you do? Where does you problem appear?

What query are you using to get the data for a single server?
